# ¿Cómo agrupo los resultados de dos tablas en XQuery?

Tags: base-de-datos, xml, xpath, xquery

Estoy ahora peleándome con XQuery para juntar dos tablas y recoger los datos necesarios de cada una. En este caso, son dos XML: uno con una lista de películas, que tiene los distintos actores, y otro con los datos de los actores.
Para unirlas, he hecho lo siguiente:

```
for $pelicula in doc("movies.xml")//movies/movie,
$actor in doc("actors.xml")//actors/actor
where $pelicula/actor=$actor/name
return <peli>{$pelicula/title, $actor/name}</peli>
```

Sin embargo, el resultado es que me devuelve el título de la película una vez por cada actor que tenga. ¿Tenéis alguna idea de como solucionar esto?
Porque mi profesor casi que no explicó lo de unir tablas. Yo sé hacerlo con SQL, pero sin el GROUP BY me siento desnudo ahora.

Un saludo

Comment: La versión actual de XQuery es 3.1 y tiene una expresión `group by` https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by.

Comment: @MartinHonnen entendido. Entonces posiblemente la versión con la que trabaja BaseX no está actualizada

Comment: Según mi experiencia, BaseX tiene una implementación completa de XQuery 3.1. Tal vez puedas o tengas que actualizar tu instalación, aunque llevamos varios años con la version XQuery 3.1 y tambien con BaseX utilizándola.